# Use number of digits to pad with `%` operator

Tags: python, printing

Consider the code:

```
>>> value = 5
>>> '%02d'%value
'05'
```

Now instead of hardcoing number of padding digits (in this case `2`) I want to use another variable for that:

```
>>> pad = 3
```

So that now I can get equivalent of:

```
>>> '%03d'%value
'005'
```

I could convert to `str` and use `zfill` but looking for a more elegant solution.

Comment: zfill is your most elegant solution. It's a programmatic function, built in, that does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1):

What version of Python are you using? In modern versions (3.6+) it is very easy to implement using f-strings:

```
f'{value:0{pad}}'
```

In earlier versions, you still can use `str.format`:

```
'{0:0{1}}'.format(value, pad)
```